# How to stop displaying (for seconds) a removed text (wordpress)?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I removed 'Private: ' in the value of the input using following code.

The problem is, it shows 'Private: ' for seconds, then disappears when loading the page.

How do I stop showing it when loading the page?

Existing code (created using plugin):

```
<form method="post" class="dwqa-content-edit-form">
     <p>
          <input type="text" name="question_title" value="Private: about your question" tabindex="1">
     </p>
</form>
```

jQuery to remove the text:

```
jQuery('.dwqa-content-edit-form p input[type=text]').each(function() {
        console.log(jQuery(this).val());
        var value = jQuery(this).val().replace("Private: ", '');
        jQuery(this).val(value);
 });
```

Comment: One solution will be keep that input hidden and show it after changing value . Also, try wrapping your code around `$(document ).ready(function() { //all code here }}` .

Comment: Hi Swati: thank you for your advice. I tried both jQuery( document ).ready(function() and 
hide -> replace -> show, but they all show the Private: for seconds, then disappears. Would you please let me know if there are other solutions? Thank you.

Comment: @Swati: Hi, I solved using hidden and show functions. Thank you for your advice and I learnt a lot from you. Have a nice weekend  : )